# Using ofstream for buffered text output to gain performance

Tags: c++, performance, file-io

I need to write a program which will write many characters in a output file.
My program will also need to write newline for better formatting.
I understand `ofstream` is a buffered stream and if we use a buffered stream for file io, we gain performance. However, if we use `std::endl` the output will be flushed and we will loose any potential performance gain due to the buffered output.

I suppose if I use `'\n'` for new line the output will be only flushed when we will `std::endl`. Is this correct? And are there any tricks that can be used to get performance gain during file output?

Note: I want to flush the buffered output at the completion of the file write operations. I think in this way I can minimize file I/O and thus can gain performance.

Comment: Do you need to flush the file or not? I don't see how you can both flush the file and also get the performance advantages of not flushing the file. (If you want optimal file write performance your best bet is probably to go with a memory mapped file.)

Comment: If you are worried about performance, you shouldnt use '<<' operators at all. you must stick to read and write methods with sufficient buffer size or memory map your file (must be done intelligently). You are correct with you uderstanding of '\n' and std::endl :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Generally, the user of stream classes shouldn't mess with the stream's flushing if maximum performance is wanted: the streams internally flush their buffer when it is full. This is actually more efficient than waiting until all output is ready, especially with large files: the buffered data is written while it is still likely to be in memory. If you create a huge buffer and only write it once the virtual memory system will have put parts of the data onto disc but not the file. It would need to be read from disc and written again.

The main point with respect to `std::endl` is that people abuse it a line ending which causes the buffer to flush and they are unaware of the performance implications. The intention of `std::endl` is that people are given control to flush files at reasonable points. For this to be effective they need to know what they are doing. Sadly, there were too many people ignorant of what `std::endl` does who advertised its use as a line ending such that it is used in many places where it is plain wrong.

That said, below are a number of things you might want to try to improve performance. I assume you need formatted output (which the use of `std::ofstream::write()` won't give you).

- Obviously, don't use `std::endl` unless you have to. If the writing code already exists and uses `std::endl` in many places, some of which possibly outside your control, you can use a filtering stream buffer which uses its internal buffer of reasonable size and which doesn't forward calls to its `sync()` function to the underlying stream buffer. Although this involves an extra copy, this is better than some spurious flushes as these are orders of magnitude more expensive.
- Although it shouldn't have an effect on `std::ofstream`s, calling `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)` used to affect the performance on some implementations. You'd want to look at using a different IOstream implementation if this has an effect because there are probably more things wrong with respect to performance.
- Make sure you are using a `std::locale` whose `std::codecvt<...>` returns `true` when calling its `always_noconv()`. This can easily be checked by using `std::use_facet<std::codecvt<char, char, stdd::mbstate_t> >(out.get_loc()).always_noconv()`. You can use `std::locale("C")` to get hold of an `std::locale` for which this should be true.
- Some locale implementations use very inefficient implementations of their numeric facets and even even if they are reasonably good, the default implementation of the `std::num_put<char>` facet may still do things you don't really need. Especially if your numeric formatting is reasonably simple, i.e. you don't keep changing formatting flags, you haven't replace mapping of characters (i.e. you don't use a funny `std::ctype<char>` facet), etc. it may be reasonable to use a custom `std::num_put<char>` facet: It is fairly easy to create a fast but simple formatting function for integer types and a good formatting function for floating points which doesn't use `snprintf()` internally.

Some people have suggested the use of memory mapped files but this only works reasonable when the size of the target file is known in advance. If this is the case this is a great way to also improve performance otherwise it isn't worth the bother. Note that you can use the stream formatting with memory mapped files (or, more generally, with any kind of output interface) by creating a custom `std::streambuf` which uses the memory mapping interface. I found memory mapping sometimes effective when using them with `std::istream`s. In many cases the differences don't really matter much.

A long time ago I wrote my own IOStreams and locales implementation which doesn't suffer from some of the performance problems mentioned above (it is available from [my site](http://www.dietmar-kuehl.de/cxxrt/) but it is a bit stale and I haven't touched it for nearly 10 years now). There are lots of things which can be improved over this implementation still but I haven't an up to date implementation which I'd be ready to post somewhere. Soon, hopefully - something I keep thinking since nearly 10 years, though...

Comment: @Kuhl thanks a lot for nice explanantion.Since use of std::endl is now in my control, I will not use std::endl. I will use \n for new line.I hope this will give me better performance. And, you are right on the spot regarding my need for formatted output.

Comment: Nearly another ten years have passed ;)

Answer (score 3):

Printing a `\n` will not (necessarily) flush the output, while printing `std::endl` or `std::flush` will.

If you want fast writing and don't care if the data is there until you're completely done, then do all of your writing with `\n` and don't worry about it (since [closing the file](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/close/) will also flush the stream).

If you're still not getting the performance you want, you could use [fstream::read(char*, int)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/read/) -- it lets you read data in whatever size blocks you want (try bigger blocks and see if it helps).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `endl` flushes the stream. Don't use it for large files.

Also make sure to set a  ***stream buffer***. At least the MSVC implementation copies *1 char at a time* to the `filebuf` when no buffer is set (see `streambuf::xsputn`). This can make your application CPU-bound, which will result in lower I/O rates.

So, add something like this to your code before doing the writing:

```
char buf[256 * 1024];
mystream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buf, sizeof(buf));
```

<sub>*NB: You can find a complete sample application [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39097696/485343).*</sub>