# Faster method to export a large 2D array into file using Cuda C

Tags: c++, c

I am fairly new to Cuda C, and I have a problem exporting a large 2D array in Cuda C using `ofstream`. The code works fine, but the performance is not really what I expected. Is there any other faster method other than `fstream`? I've tried using `ostringstream` but it doesn't really show any improvements.

```
HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy( sseismo, seismo,sizeof(float)*(DIMX*samp),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost ) );
sprintf(nmfile, "seismo%ix%itau%08ivz.txt",4000,4000,1 );
std::ofstream outseis(nmfile); // output, normal file
for (int jj=0; jj<4000; jj++) 
{
    for (int ii=0; ii<4000; ii++) 
    {
    int ij=(DIMX)*jj + ii;           
    outseis<<sseismo[ij]<<" ";   
    }
    outseis<<"\n";
}
outseis.close();
```

Comment: In "CUDA C" the host code is passed off to the host compiler.  This question has nothing to do with CUDA.

Comment: If you decide to use binary format as Eric suggested, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563963/writing-a-binary-file-in-c-very-fast) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could output the data in binary format rather than text format.

```
outseis.write((char*)sseismo[jj*(DIMX)], 4000*sizeof(sseismo[0]));
```

Otherwise `outseis<<` is almost the fastest text output you could get.

Please refer to here for more info about `std::ofstream::write`

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write

Comment: well, thank you.. turns out it much more efficient using binary format as an output file..

Answer (score 0):

If writing binary data isn't an option, you can squeeze a few hundred milliseconds by writing the inner loop to a stringstream and writing that to the file (I get 1.317ms instead of ~1.700ms).

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    const char nmfile[] = "out.txt";
    std::ofstream outseis(nmfile); // output, normal file

    for (int jj=0; jj<4000; jj++)
    {
            std::stringstream buf;
            for (int ii=0; ii<4000; ii++)
            {
                    int ij = jj + ii;
                    buf<<ij<<" ";
            }
            outseis << buf.str() << "\n";

    }
    outseis.close();
}
```