# Improving performance of ofstream?

Tags: c++, stream, ofstream, fifo

I am communicating with some parallel processes using FIFOs. I am reading the pipe with read(). And I am writing to the named pipe by doing this:

```
ofstream pipe(namepipe);

pipe << data << endl;
pipe.close();
```

I have been noticing that the performance is horrible though! It takes like 40ms sometimes. It's an extreme latency in my opinion. I read that the use of std::endl can affect performance. Should I avoid using endl?

Does using ofstream affect performance? Are there any other alternatives to this method?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When working with large files with `fstream`, make sure to ***use a stream buffer*** and don't use `endl` (`endl` flushes the output stream).

At least the MSVC implementation copies *1 char at a time* to the `filebuf` when no buffer was set (see `streambuf::xsputn()`), which can make your application CPU-bound, which will result in lower I/O rates.

So, try adding this to your code before doing the writing:

```
const size_t bufsize = 256*1024;
char buf[bufsize];
mystream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buf, bufsize);
```

<sub>*NB: You can find a complete sample application [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39097696/485343).*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

A cheap hack:

```
std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

**Note** *Use this only if you are not going to be mixing `c` IO with `c++`*

The reason `std::endl` might affect i/o performance is because it flushes the stream. So to avoid this, you should use `'\n'`

Avoiding having to open and close multiple streams will also help

Comment: I am kind of mixing them though. I am using read() which is from <stdio.h> I think. I am using this in a thread though, and the C++ iostream on the main thread. Should I still use std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);?

Comment: @LuisCruz, if you are doing that then you shouldn't use that suggestion. Alternatively, I will suggest doing all your IO in C rather than mixing the two. Or switch entirely to C++ IO because you can still do the same stuff in C++. See [read](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/), then you can make use of the optimization I have shown