# Convert cout statements to fwrite functions

Tags: c++

I managed to compile the following main function using Windows Studio 2012 under a 64 bit release configuration: https://github.com/kpu/kenlm/blob/master/lm/builder/dump_counts_main.cc

Because I will be using it process TB of [data](http://data.statmt.org/ngrams/counts_en/) I wanted to see if I could direct the output directly to a file instead of through `cout`. While I have found good [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563963/writing-a-binary-file-in-c-very-fast) on how to write files to disk fast I am not exactly sure how to pass the following statements into the `fwrite` functions.

```
std::cout << vocab.Lookup(*i) << ' ';
std::cout << *reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t*>(words + order) << '\n';
```

Anyone have any idea how they can be converted to an array of elements converted to a `const void*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, to clear any misconceptions you might have:

- `fwrite` is still (usually) buffered I/O (and that's a good thing)
- `ofstream` is a perfectly good interface for doing formatted output to file
- and `ostream` (and thus all of its derived classes) have the `write` member which serves the same purpose as `fwrite`.
- and if you really insist on using `cout` for I/O, you can do `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);` at the beginning of your program, so that the iostream library doesn't have to bend over backwards to make writes to `cout` interoperate with stdio operations on `STDOUT`.

... but to answer the question you asked, you can just use a `stringstream`. You do formatted output to the string stream, then you extract the string it creates so that you can write its characters with `fwrite`.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to C++ so your answer provided some much needed context. My assumption is that its going to be faster to write direct to file via `ofstream` than piping the `cout` output into a text file from command prompt.