# Most efficient possible code for printing a specific board C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, multidimensional-array

So I am trying to print a board **exactly** like this with the multidimensional array

`char score[10][10] = {' '};`

```
   a b c d e f g h i j
  +-------------------+
 0|                   |
 1|                   |
 2|                   |
 3|                   |
 4|                   |
 5|                   |
 6|                   |
 7|                   |
 8|                   |
 9|                   |
  +-------------------+
```

Currently this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char score[10][10] = {' '};

    cout << "   a b c d e f g h i j" << endl;
    cout << "  +-------------------+" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << " " << i << "|";
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            cout << score[i][j];
        }
        if(i == 0) {
            cout << "                  |";
        } else {
            cout << "                   |";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "  +-------------------+" << endl;
}
```

As you can see my code is inefficient and lengthy.

What would be the most efficient possible way ( or a more efficient way) of printing the board as exactly shown above with the multidimensional score array?

Comment: Might want to try here: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Other than the indentation is broken, this code looks fine.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that short code doesn't always mean efficient code and vice versa

Comment: Is this proving to be a bottle neck in your code? If not I would just fix the indentation and use this.  It's clear and concise and I doubt it's too slow.

Comment: I don't know why are you talking to "efficiency" in a so simply code???

Comment: That code doesn't work properly, by the way. At least, it only works if the first and only char in the 2d array is a space.  ( If you're not going to use the array, you can get away with a much less intricate inner loop consisting of just  cout << " " << i << "|                   |" << '\n';    (you'll need to add some spaces this site removed from between the two bar characters there)  )

Comment: @Poldie His code will work fine. I think a better way to put it is that his table may have unexpected characters, not just spaces. Saying his code doesn't work implies it will throw an error during compile or run-time.

Comment: @Daniel Populate his array, with the code as-is, and see what you get.   Yes, a run-time error; the wrong result - a badly formatted table.

Comment: For the record: your code is neither inefficient nor lengthy. (Only the `if(i == 0)` part seems .. redundant? An error?)

Comment: @Jongware It's to cope with that single space in the array I keep going on about!   The code needs a tweak to handle the array being populated properly.

Comment: @Poldie What do you mean "populate his array"? His code compiled and runs fine for me. Yes, he should be using `{{' '}}` and it will only set the first char to a space but it's still compilable as-is. The uninitialized values should still print out as characters, they will just be pseudo-random.

Comment: this question should be in code review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Jongware `if (i == 0)` is not redundant, your thinking of `if (i != 0)`, either way, `i` is an integer and should be treated as thus. Doing things like `if (!i)` only obscures the meaning of `i` and is hardly quicker than a comparison.

Comment: @Daniel I'm assuming this code is supposed to display the contents of that array when it's populated; for example, to output the current state of a Battleships game.  As it stands it won't do that. If you fill it with, for example, a mixture of 'o' and 'x' the output is wrong.  He fills the array with binary zero except for the first char, so it generally outputs nothing. Why do you think he has to print all those spaces in each line?

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have pointed out, your code is almost efficient as possible. Making it shorter would do little to its run-time and instead obscure its meaning. There are however a few things you can do to speed it up.

1. Avoid an extra call to `operator<<`, evaluation of `std::end`, and [unnecessary buffer flushes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9427029/1313439) by using `\n` and including it in your existing string literals (evaluated at compile time).
2. Use `printf` instead of `cout`. See "performance" section of [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20238349/1313439).

Comment: In the old days, we would overload endl to handle record oriented streams where '\n' would just be another character.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by others, there are not many ways to make this more efficient, particularly if constrained to use the `cout` stream.

But for the "lengthy" part, this is a few lines and characters shorter, albeit C++11:

```
cout << "   a b c d e f g h i j\n"
        "  +-------------------+\n";
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cout << ' ' << i << '|';
    for (char s : score[i])
      cout << s;
    cout << "         |\n";
}
cout << "  +-------------------+\n";
```

I don't understand why the spaces should be printed at the end instead of aligning the inner columns nicely, but I followed what you did in your code.

I have also got rid of the unnecessary `endl` which triggers stream flush and changed single letter strings to character constants, but I'm a bit doubtful of the resulting efficiency gain there. After all, it's just printing some output, not a time-critical computation task.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that when you said you wanted to make it **efficient** and **not lengthy** what you really meant was that you wanted it to be **correct** and **readable**.

I don't believe what you currently have is "correct". I assume that `char score[10][10]` will contain a single printable character for each square of the board and perhaps a null character for cells where you don't want to print anything. And you want to print the contents of `score` into the template shown. As it stands, if you put anything other than a single space into char `score[10][10]` you will mess up your template.

As for readability, I think what you currently have is reasonably readable, perhaps it would benefit by having some [functions extracted](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) with meaningful names but that is just my personal preference. Based on my assumptions about what you were trying to do here is my corrected and refactored version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void printHeader() {
  std::cout << "   a b c d e f g h i j\n";
  std::cout << "  +-------------------+\n";
}

void printFooter() {
  std::cout << "  +-------------------+\n";
}

void printRowStart(int i) {
  std::cout << " " << i << "|";
}

void printRowEnd() {
  std::cout << "|\n";
}

void printSquare(char score) {
  char printable_score = (score != '\0') ? score : ' ';
  std::cout << printable_score;
}

void printRowScore(char (&row_score)[10]) {
  printSquare(row_score[0]);
  for (int i = 1; i != 10; ++i) {
    std::cout << " ";
    printSquare(row_score[i]);
  }
}

void printScore(char (&score)[10][10]) {
  printHeader();
  for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {
    printRowStart(i);
    printRowScore(score[i]);
    printRowEnd();
  }
  printFooter();
}

int main(){
  char score[10][10] = { { 0 } };

  // Added to test assumed usage
  score[4][5] = 'x';
  score[4][6] = 'x';

  printScore(score);
}
```

You might also want to consider making the code print to a generic `ostream` to make it more testable.